# Why does OpenSSL return 0 even though there's an error?

Tags: bash, openssl

I performed

```
openssl rsa -check -in foo.key
```

and received

> RSA key error: dmq1 not congruent to d

Nevertheless,

> shell> echo $?
>
> 0

Why should I receive a return code of 0 even though there's an error?

Comment: The return code of a program hasn't anything to do with the shell.  It's upto the program what it chooses to return.  If you think that `openssl` should exit with a return code of non-zero in your case, consider filing a bug report (for openssl).

Comment: Thanks. My question is particularly regarding openssl. I was wondering if there's some standard practice, design decision that would motivate openssl to return that return code or perhaps it's simply an error in their implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is a design choice, but if you check the `OpenSSL` source you will observe the following:

`apps/rsa.c` uses `RSA_check_key()` to check the validity of a key. The manpage tells us:

`man RSA_check_key`:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>   This function validates RSA keys. It checks that p and q are in fact prime, and that n = p*q.
>   It also checks that d*e = 1 mod (p-1*q-1), and that dmp1, dmq1 and iqmp are set correctly or are NULL.
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> RETURN VALUE
>
> ```
>   RSA_check_key() returns 1 if rsa is a valid RSA key, and 0 otherwise.  -1 is returned if an error occurs while checking the key.
>   If the key is invalid or an error occurred, the reason code can be obtained using ERR_get_error(3).
> ```

As such, it differenciates between keys that it cannot parse at all (`-1`) and keys that have invalid properties (`0`), e.g. non-primes.

The wrapping code (`apps/rsa.c`) does exit with an error (`1`) in case `RSA_check_key()` returns `-1` but does not in case it returns `0` (see the control flow wrt/ setting `ret` and `goto end;`).

It certainly *looks* like it's a deliberate choice not to error out in this case, but I agree, it seems strange. You might want to ask on the `OpenSSL` mailing list, I'm sure someone there can shed some light on this particular behavior (and it might be a bug after all).

Comment: @ChaimKut, did you eventually asked about this on the OpenSSL mailing list ?