# Why do OpenSSL crypto functions return 1 on success, 0 on failure?

Tags: c, openssl, return-value

Been writing code that uses OpenSSL, and I've noticed that, confusingly, most of the crypto library functions return 1 for success and 0 for failure:

- [RSA_public_decrypt fails when using RSA_set0_key(key, n,e,d)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967235/rsa-public-decrypt-fails-when-using-rsa-set0-keykey-n-e-d/44981349#44981349)
- https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html
- https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/57d7b988b498ed34e98d1957fbbded8342f2a952/include/openssl/ec.h#L464
- https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/doc/man3/EVP_EncryptInit.pod#examples

So my question is, why does OpenSSL not use the typical C/POSIX standard [return values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9549375/4364036) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does OpenSSL return 0 even though there's an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888630/why-does-openssl-return-0-even-though-theres-an-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditionally, in C, an integer value of `0` stands for `false` and `1` stands for `true` and OpenSSL follows that convention. See [this section of the Wikipedia page about the Boolean data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type#C,_C++,_Objective-C,_AWK) for some context:

> Initial implementations of the language C (1972) provided no Boolean
>   type, and to this day Boolean values are commonly represented by
>   integers (ints) in C programs. The comparison operators (>, ==, etc.)
>   are defined to return a signed integer (int) result, either 0 (for
>   false) or 1 (for true).

This has changed somewhat with the introduction of the `_Bool` type in C99 but the initial implementation  OpenSSL predates that -- hence the use of the integer values of `0` and `1`. Also, in some cases OpenSSL functions use different integer values to indicate different types of results.

The [SO answer on return values that you have pointed to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9549375/4364036) is specifically about the special case of the exit value of a process, to be returned to its parent. Indeed, for that particular situation a value of zero indicates success. But that is not a typical approach applied to function return values in general.

Comment: _most_ POSIX API calls return `0` on success.
_most_ OPENSSL API calls return '1' on success. except openssl isn't even self-consistent. the AES_KEY api calls return `0` on success, for example.